# MongoDB - fast count of documents associated with indexed key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to query a mongoDB (version 4.0)collection with 100M documents based on indexed field.
For example if I have a collection of users and each user has a field of city which is a string and this field is indexed I want to ask how many users have some exact value in the city field (`db.users.count({address:"New York"})`).
I see that the response time to  is changing according to the number of results if there are 20M it is around 5 sec.
In the explain() I see that it using COUNT and there is index name

```
"stage" : "COUNT_SCAN"
```

and

```
"indexName" : "address_1"
```

My question is doesn't mongodb save the number of documents related to each indexed field key for quick retrieval without scanning?
Is there a quick way to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

`db.users.find({address: 'New York'}).count()` which I think it's faster since you have indexed `address` key. I don't think that in mongoDB saves anywhere this information regarding how many items are in a collection based on an indexed key. Just retrieving the data using the indexed key and perform a `.count()` should be pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesnt.
However, another improvement possible:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({address:1});
db.users.find({{address: 'New York}).count();
```